# Исчезают окна при наведении курсора мыши

Tags: windows, windows-10

У меня 10 винда, и три дня назад я поставил новый антивирус - PRO32TotalSecurity. Вечером того же дня, когда был установлен антивирус, у меня возникла такая проблема: допустим, у меня есть два .txt файла, открываю их оба, а затем сворачиваю. Потом навожу курсор мыши на нужный - всё исчезает, я опять навожу - исчезает, иногда схватывает и не исчезает.Может быть дело в новом антивирусе? Что можно сделать? Просто из-за этого пользоваться ноутбуком невозможно

Comment: Самая старая новость на их сайте - апрель этого года. Ты уверен, что хочешь ставить столь известный, распространённый и зарекомендовавший себя продукт?

Comment: Он уже поставлен как несколько дней

Comment: Ты не понял что я написал. Прочти пожалуйста, ещё раз.